# What % of users are still playing the game daily?

Tags: data-science, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I am going to share a question that I was asked in a data science interview. I failed the interview as I couldn't answer the question and still now I don't have any idea how to solve it.

Below a data table is given. It's about number of users of a mobile game.
Users Assigned = Newly added users on a day.
Active users = Total users active on a day.
[image]

The question is- What % of users are still playing the game daily?
Options are

1. Almost 5%
2. Almost 10% to 15%.
   And I was ask to show the step by step processes.

It was my first-ever interview in life, so I was nervous and couldn't solve within given time. I hope someone will answer me here and will explain it clearly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On day 0 you have `4051` users, all of which are active.
On day 1 you have `4095` added users meaning `4051+4095`, of which `5522` are active.

Given that registration seems to indicate activity, we have to exclude those that registered today, meaning
`Day 1 active users = (5522-4095) / (4051+4095) = 0.1751780015 => 18%`

Continue this until day 6 when you have `6820` active with a total playerbase of `4051+4095+3868+3921+4010+4070+4001`

`Day 6 = (6820-4001) / (4051+4095+3868+3921+4010+4070+4001) = 0.1006210737 =>10%`